# Django Models: Set database constrains using annotations

Tags: django-models

I have a model that has several reverse relations, and I need that only one of this relations to be not null. For example:

```
class MediaFile(models.Model):
    uploaded_file = models.FileFiled...

class Customer(models.Model):
    profile_picture = models.Foreignkey(to='MediaFile' ... )
    id_picture = models.Foreignkey(to='MediaFile' ... )
```

using database constraints on the MediaFile model, I want to make sure a single media_file not to be used more that once (in any field of any customer). For instance, I want to avoid a customers profile_picture, not to be used for id_picture or profile_picture of another or the same customer.

I wanted to use models.CheckConstraint and use an annotated field called "number_of_usages" and set models.Q(number_of_usages__lte=1). but couldn't. I'm using django 3.2 and postgres 13.12

Comment: You can not use annotations, not only because Django does not support that, but even if it did, a CHECK constraint has as "scope" a single line.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use annotations, not only because Django does not support that, but even if it did, a CHECK constraint has as "scope" a single line.

You can easily check that the `profile_picture` is different from the `id_picture` with a `CheckConstraint`, and you can also check that the two `profile_picture`s are unique with a `UniqueConstraint`, but what is not very easy is to check if a `profile_picture` of one `Customer` is different from the `id_picture` of another user.

This might however be possible with *linearization*, indeed, by just making a model that for each `Customer` and each image produces a "role" of that image and its `Customer`, like:

```
class MediaFile(models.Model):
    uploaded_file = models.FileField()


class Customer(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField(MediaFile, through='CustomerImage')


class CustomerImage(models.Model):
    picture = models.OneToOneField(MediaFile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    role = models.CharField(choices=[('p', 'profile picture', 'i', 'id picture')])
    customer = models.Foreignkey(MediaFile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

this will then link the `MediaFile` with a `Customer`, and because of the `OneToOneField`, which is essentially a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`, we know that the same `MediaFile`, will occur at most once in the `CustomerImage` table.